# Controlling a UIView on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to control a UIView that comes out from the side of the screen when a user swipes left or right. Since I want the view to follow the users finger I am using a pan gesture.

All of the is working okay however the code is growing as I am looking for speed of swipe and when touches end or start to get that information. The reason I am not using a slider-out navigation type of setup, is due to the fact that this view has to be part of UIWindow so it sits onto of my UITabBar, not under it.

The problem I have is stopping the view from moving past a certain point. This is the code I tried:

In the pan gesture method:

```
if (self.filterView.frame.origin.x <=36){

        gesture.enabled = NO;

    }
```

This works however as the code does; it disables the gesture and swiping back no longer works. I tried this as well:

```
if (self.filterView.frame.origin.x <=36){

    return; 

}
```

however, this means when I swipe back, nothing happens obviously as this code executes first to check the position.

```
if (self.filterView.frame.origin.x <=36){

     self.filterView.frame = CGRectMake(37, 0, 300, 500);
    return; 
}
```

This was the closest match - however a bug is present where it resets the view - which is correct as that's what the code does. It's not very efficient and doesn't look good.

What is a better way to solve this problem? I just want self.filterView to not go bast a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the view has passed the point, like you are doing. Then you want to manually keep it at that point.

```
// this checks if the view's origin along the x-axis has gone less than or equal to 36.0f
if (CGRectGetMinX(self.filterView.frame) <= 36.0f)
{
    CGRect currentFrame = self.filterView.frame;
    currentFrame.x = 37.0f;
    self.filterView.frame = currentFrame;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This sort of works, However the IView flickers if I try pas that point. Any ideas?